# What does "run '${appserver.home}/bin/startup.bat'" mean?

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I am following a step-by-step guide to write a Spring application, and I have installed ant and tomcat. Everything works so far, but now I am at a sentence that says this:

"Let's just quickly start Tomcat by running '${appserver.home}/bin/startup.bat'"

What does this mean? Where am I supposed to run this? How do I do this?

I tried typing "{appserver.home}/bin/startup.bat" into the command line, and this did not work.

Please help? What does the author mean by that sentence?

Comment: `${appserver.home}` is a symbolic variable pointing to your tomcat

Answer (score 2):

${appserver.home} here represents the directory where Tomcat is installed. Inside it, there's a directory called bin, and inside of that is the startup.bat file that you should run.